# Which version of log4cxx is combined with ROS?

Tags: ros, log4cxx, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering which version of log4cxx is combined with ROS. Because, the logcxx properties file which I have written is not parsing rolling policy and triggering policy. Later I came to know that, there is a resolved-bug based on configuring the properties file to support rolling and triggering policy. Even though bug has been resolved in 2008, I don't see it as reflected on the ROS indigo version that I use in my computer.

Any one guide me on this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211272/which-version-of-log4cxx-is-combined-with-ros-?/) by [yagamiram](https://answers.ros.org/users/22787/yagamiram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses Ubuntu's version of log4cxx. It looks like Ubuntu have been packaging log4cxx 0.10.0 since at least 12.04, according to their [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=log4cxx&searchon=sourcenames)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yagamiram](https://answers.ros.org/users/22787/yagamiram/) on 2015-06-14**:
Oh thanks for the information.
Just in case, have you tried using rolling and triggering policy in the log4cxx before with the latest version ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-06-14**:
I haven't. You should be able to trace your bug report and fix through to the first version of log4cxx where it was fixed, and you should be able to follow that version to determine if it's released in Ubuntu or not.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-06-14**:
I suspect there aren't many people on this forum who use log4cxx extensively, beyond the logging that ROS already provides. I've answered your question about which version ships with ROS; you may need to ask elsewhere for help debugging issues that are specific to log4cxx.